# What is the difference between "on-screen", "on screen" and "on the screen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is there any difference between these three notions or they can be used interchangeably? For example:

1. There are screenshots of CNN news on the screen;
2. There are screenshots of CNN news on screen;
3. There are screenshots of CNN news on-screen.

I also saw this variant: "On-screen screenshot of CNN news".
Is this variant correct?

Would be nice to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 and 3 are both correct for what I think you are trying to say. Number 2 and 3 both mean "The screen is displaying CNN news", interchangeably. Number 1 is improper, as "on the screen" is used to say "Oh look, there's a hair on the screen. I am going to wipe it off".